# When i run "mvn -Dtest=Hello#test test" then " java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class" is coming

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, maven-2, google-sheets-api, maven-surefire-plugin

Actully when i run the **mvn -Dtest=Hello#test test** then below error is coming like cannot inherit from final class. but that class that i'm using has no final keyword used, but still i'm getting this error.

i have tried almost all the solutions from by googling but not getting exact cause for this. can anyone help???

```js
jagadeesh@jagadeesh-HP-EliteBook-840-G2:~/Desktop/eclipseworkspace/getDataFromSheet2$ mvn -Dtest=Hello#test test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building getDataFromSheet2 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ getDataFromSheet2 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 7 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ getDataFromSheet2 ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ getDataFromSheet2 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ getDataFromSheet2 ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test (default-test) @ getDataFromSheet2 ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[ERROR] There are test failures.

Please refer to /home/jagadeesh/Desktop/eclipseworkspace/getDataFromSheet2/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
Exception in provider
org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireExecutionException: Exception in provider
 at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.InPluginVMSurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(InPluginVMSurefireStarter.java:91)
 at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1166)
 at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1011)
 at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:857)
 at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.IsolatedClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedClassLoader.java:100)
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
 at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
 at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.tryGetMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:60)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit3.JUnit3TestChecker.isSuiteOnly(JUnit3TestChecker.java:66)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit3.JUnit3TestChecker.isValidJUnit3Test(JUnit3TestChecker.java:61)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit3.JUnit3TestChecker.accept(JUnit3TestChecker.java:56)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit4.JUnit4TestChecker.accept(JUnit4TestChecker.java:53)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.DefaultScanResult.applyFilter(DefaultScanResult.java:102)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.scanClassPath(JUnit4Provider.java:309)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.setTestsToRun(JUnit4Provider.java:189)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:132)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2(ReflectionUtils.java:206)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:161)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:84)
 at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.InPluginVMSurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(InPluginVMSurefireStarter.java:87)
 ... 25 more

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.346 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-12-11T16:45:16+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/216M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

i'm using java version:

```html
java version "1.8.0_191"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
```

Maven version:

```html
Apache Maven 3.3.9
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_191, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.15.0-42-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Below is my pom.xml file....

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>getDataFromSheet2</groupId>
  <artifactId>getDataFromSheet2</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  

<properties>

 <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
 <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
 <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
  
<build>
<plugins>
<!-- 
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <release>8</release>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
    </configuration>
</plugin> -->
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
    <!--  <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.20.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>  -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <forkCount>0</forkCount>
        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
    
    <!-- <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.21.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <forkCount>0</forkCount>
        <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin> -->
</plugins>
</build>
  
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.22.1</version>
  <type>maven-plugin</type>
</dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
    <version>1.48.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.gdata</groupId>
   <artifactId>core</artifactId>
   <version>1.47.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
   <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
   <version>1.20.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>22.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava-jdk5 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
    <version>13.0</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client-auth-oauth2</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3-alpha</version>
</dependency>
  
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-sheets -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-sheets</artifactId>
    <version>v4-rev2-1.22.0</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.http-client/google-http-client -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.22.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.http-client/google-http-client-jackson2 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
    <version>1.22.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.oauth-client/google-oauth-client -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.22.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
<!-- <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3</version>
</dependency>
 -->
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.9</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.oauth-client/google-oauth-client-java6 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-oauth-client-java6</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.0-beta</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.oauth-client/google-oauth-client-jetty -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.0-beta</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
    <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.15</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.14.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
    <version>3.14.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.8.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload -->

    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>
  
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
<!-- <dependency>
    <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.2</version>
</dependency>
 -->

  
  </dependencies>
  
</project>
```

Below is my java file(**Hello.java**) that i am running via "mvn -Dtest=Hello#test test".

```js
package getDataFromSheet2.getDataFromSheet2;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetService;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.ListEntry;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.ListFeed;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetEntry;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetFeed;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.WorksheetEntry;
import com.google.gdata.util.ServiceException;


public class Hello {
 public String ServiceAccountEmailID = "My_seviceAcountMail";//replace with your service account mail, your goggle sheet must be shared with this email for accessibility 
 public String P12 = "./src/main/resources/data-630b4f318e43.p12";//replace with your P12 path
 public static SpreadsheetService SERVICE = new SpreadsheetService("google sheet data");//keep anything prefer as Project name which u created in google
 public URL SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL;
 public String SPREADSHEET_NAME="Links";//Update with Google sheet name which u want to access
    public static String[] outputOfProperty=null;
 public static String[] outputOfPropertyValues=null;
 public static String[] outputOfImageURLs=null;
 public static int iOfProperty=0,iOfImageURLs=0,iOfPropertyValues=0;
 @Test
 public void test() throws IOException, ServiceException, GeneralSecurityException {
  
 System.out.println("Hello chinna");
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.runtime.version"));

    Hello con=new Hello();
 SpreadsheetEntry spreadSheet= con.getSpreadSheet();
 List<WorksheetEntry> worksheets = spreadSheet.getWorksheets();
 System.out.println(worksheets.get(0).getTitle().getPlainText());
 int rows=worksheets.get(1).getRowCount();

    URL listFeedUrl = ((WorksheetEntry) spreadSheet.getWorksheets().get(1)).getListFeedUrl();

 System.out.println("Successfully connected");//Now u can operate with spreadsheet 
 
 
    ListFeed feed = (ListFeed) SERVICE.getFeed(listFeedUrl, ListFeed.class);
 
    System.out.println(feed.getEntries().size());
   
    
    outputOfProperty=new String[feed.getEntries().size()];
    System.out.println(outputOfProperty.length);
    outputOfImageURLs=new String[feed.getEntries().size()];
    System.out.println(outputOfImageURLs.length);
    outputOfPropertyValues=new String[feed.getEntries().size()];
    System.out.println(outputOfPropertyValues.length);
for(ListEntry entry : feed.getEntries()){
 
// System.out.println(entry);
//   System.out.println("new row");
      for(String tag : entry.getCustomElements().getTags()){
//        System.out.println(entry.getCustomElements().getValue(tag));
        outputOfProperty[iOfProperty]=entry.getCustomElements().getValue(tag);
        iOfProperty++;
        break;
      }
      
      boolean second =true;
      for(String tag : entry.getCustomElements().getTags()){
     if(!second) {
      outputOfImageURLs[iOfImageURLs]=entry.getCustomElements().getValue(tag);
      iOfImageURLs++;
//      System.out.println(entry.getCustomElements().getValue(tag));
            break; 
     }
     second=false;
      }
      
      int check=1;
      for(String tag : entry.getCustomElements().getTags()){
     if(check==3) {
      outputOfPropertyValues[iOfPropertyValues]=entry.getCustomElements().getValue(tag);
      iOfPropertyValues++;
//      System.out.println(entry.getCustomElements().getValue(tag));
            break; 
     }
     check++;
      }
      
      

    }
 }
 
   public  SpreadsheetEntry getSpreadSheet() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, ServiceException {
   SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet = null;
   SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full");
   AuthenticateWithGoogleAPI();
   SpreadsheetFeed feed = SERVICE.getFeed(SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL, SpreadsheetFeed.class);
   List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = feed.getEntries();
   if (spreadsheets.size() == 0) {
    System.out.println("No Spreadsheets Available.");
    throw new ServiceException("No spread Sheet Found");
   } else {
    for(SpreadsheetEntry ss : spreadsheets){
     if(ss.getTitle().getPlainText().equals(SPREADSHEET_NAME)){
      spreadsheet = ss;
      break;
     }
    }
    return spreadsheet;
   }
  }

  public void AuthenticateWithGoogleAPI() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
   File p12 = new File(P12);
   HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
   JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
   String[] SCOPESArray = { "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",
     "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full", "https://docs.google.com/feeds" };
   final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(SCOPESArray);
   GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport)
     .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory).setServiceAccountId(ServiceAccountEmailID).setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
     .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(p12).build();
   credential.refreshToken();
   String accessToken = credential.getAccessToken();
   SERVICE.setProtocolVersion(SpreadsheetService.Versions.V3);
   SERVICE.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
   SERVICE.setOAuth2Credentials(credential); 
  }
  
 
 
 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jagadeesh you have bad dependencies in the pom.xml. I have cleaned up the noise and commented out some dependencies that are not required. Most of the time you would want to let the dependencies be transitively resolved when you start working on a project. Once you know which version of libraries are compatible, then you can start adding exclusions if needed. The updated POM that works for me follows and here's a reference if you need to dig deeper [VerifyError](https://github.com/googleapis/google-oauth-java-client/issues/54)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>getDataFromSheet2</groupId>
    <artifactId>getDataFromSheet2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <forkCount>0</forkCount>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
        </dependency>
        <!--dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
            <version>1.48.0</version>
        </dependency-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gdata</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>1.47.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>22.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
            <version>13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client-auth-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3-alpha</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-sheets</artifactId>
            <version>v4-rev2-1.22.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.22.0</version>
        </dependency-->
        <!--dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
            <version>1.22.0</version>
        </dependency-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.22.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client-java6</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.0-beta</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.0-beta</version>
        </dependency-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
            <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Glad I could help!